# Transferring django app to server through scp?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, scp, django

Firstly I want to note that I am both beginner in deploying Django app and Linux overall.

I saw that it's possible to transfer Django app to the server through SCP in one of Corey Schafer's [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds)
Before that, I was using git to push and pull files to my server in order to get changes. I really don't know the best practice, all I know that for so small stupid change(for example testing something) git isn't the right way. 
 The thing is, I am not bothered to write a small shell script for sending files via scp but it doesn't support excluding files, folders. in my case, what do I use?
I tried zipping and sending files and unzipping in the server, but that's a pain in the ass too.

Answer (score 0):

I used rsync over ssh. I also added some variables(dsp - django set path) in sshd_config, so to sum it up my new cute little command is rs:

```
alias rs="rsync -e \"ssh\" -a --exclude={'.git','env','secrets.json','.vscode','static'}\
src_folder dsp:dest_folder --stats"
```